# subset rows in data table with many columns

Tags: r, datatable

I'm trying my best to not compute on rows using `data.table` since it's not advisable. I want to subset all rows that have a value greater or equal to `2` of a large `data.table` that has many columns, and potentially thereafter also get the columns.

Reproducible example:

```
 DT <- as.data.table( rbind( diag(5)+1, diag(5), rep(0,5)) )
 DT[1,1] = 1
```

My code:

```
DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) x>=2 )]
```

I get a `data.table` of booleans, confused now how I should subset this.

One approach that works mentioned by @IRTFM is:

```
DT[DT[,apply(.SD, 1, function(x) any(x>=2))]]

    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  1  2  1  1  1
2:  1  1  2  1  1
3:  1  1  1  2  1
4:  1  1  1  1  2
```

Now how I should also subset the columns that have a `2` value ??

Desirable result is:

```
      V2 V3 V4 V5
1:    2  1  1  1
2:    1  2  1  1
3:    1  1  2  1
4:    1  1  1  2
```

Comment: I think that way you get a logical vector for each column. Have you tried apply(.SD, 1, function(x){any(x>=2)}) in the i position.

Comment: Here's code for a much more compact example: `DT <- as.data.frame( rbind( diag(5)+1, diag(5), rep(0,5)) )`  Now it's your job to specify what you want returned from this. Your current description seems imprecise to me.

Comment: ok updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get your example to load in my console session but this is a much more "minima;" example that demonstrates a method. Not sure if it has the usual data.table efficiency though:

```
DT <- setDT( data.frame(x=1:2, y=0,z=0))
DT[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x){any(x>=2)}) ] gets you a logical vector for each row
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
DT[ DT[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x){any(x>=2)}) ]] # uses that vector to select rows
   x y z
1: 2 0 0
```

This should succeed as well:

```
DT[ as.logical(rowSums(DT >= 2))]
   x y z
1: 2 0 0
```

For the second part consider this:

```
cols <- sapply(DT, function(x){ any(x>0)})
DT2[ ,.SD, .SDcols=names(cols[cols])]
```

Comment: I don't want to sum rows, just check if a data point is greater or equal to `2` in the `data.table` and potentially also subset the columns which the subset appeared afterwards. like   x y z
2 0 0 but with only x

Comment: sorry the example is too big and it's not loading correctly, you are right.

Comment: another doubt is that with this example you made , we could not really escape to operate through rows since the `apply` is doing that

Comment: I wasn't summing rows. I was testing whether the rows had any value greater than 2. So the second attempt was wrong. I thought you wanted any row that had an instance of value greater than or equal to 2. Do you want only the columns with any instance of that feature?

Comment: no I want any row that had an instance of value greater than or equal to 2, but if possible to return only the columns where that instance appeared. so this `DT[ DT[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x){any(x>=2)}) ]]` to return only the `x` column, many thanks. I'm tripped up by the syntax in data.table